# Infinite while-loop in BASH script

Tags: bash, infinite-loop

I'm really struggling to see why this while-loop never ends, when the loop starts, my variable LOC is set to Testing/, which is a directory I created to test this program, it has the following layout:
[image: Layout of my Testing Directory]

I want the loop to end once all Directories have had the "count" function applied to them.
Here are the things I have tried;

I've checked my count function, and it doesn't produce an infinite loop

I've tried running through the algorithm by hand

```
PARSE=1
LOC=$LOC/
count
AVAILABLEDIR=$(ls $LOC -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "/$" | awk '{ print $9 }')
while [ $PARSE = "1" ]
do

if [[ ${AVAILABLEDIR[@]} == '' ]]; then
    PARSE=0
fi

DIRBASE=$LOC

for a in ${AVAILABLEDIR[@]}; do
LOC="${DIRBASE}${a}"
LOCLIST="$LOCLIST $LOC"
count
done

for a in ${LOCLIST[@]}; do
TMPAVAILABLEDIR=$(ls $a -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "/$" | awk '{ print $9 }')
PREPEND=$a
if [[ ${TMPAVAILABLEDIR[@]} == '' ]]; then
    continue
fi

for a in ${TMPAVAILABLEDIR[@]}; do
    TMPAVAILABLEDIR2="$TMPAVAILABLEDIR2 ${PREPEND[@]}${a}"
done

NEWAVAILABLEDIR="$NEWAVAILABLEDIR $TMPAVAILABLEDIR2"
done

AVAILABLEDIR=$NEWAVAILABLEDIR
NEWAVAILABLEDIR=''
LOC=''
done
```

I am really struggling, and any input would be greatly appreciated, I've been trying to figure this out for the last couple of hours.

Comment: Never parse output from ls. What exactly you are trying to do? May be it must be much simpler?

Comment: I have to, I'm trying to count files, folders and folder sizes. except without using "find", "locate" or "du" or any sort of recursive function.

Comment: have a read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Why do you reject recursive functions which do what you need?

Comment: Related: *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to run the script with argument -x, or write it into the first line:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
```

Then it tells you everything it does.

In that case, you might notice two errors:

1. You never reset TMPAVAILABLEDIR2
2. You do ls on regular files as well.

Comment: I also noticed that I don't reset LOCLIST, but thank you for the inspiration to check whether I reset everything!

Answer (score 1):

You wrote you want to perform "count" on all directories.
Look at the options of *[find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix))*:

```
find $LOC -type d | while read dir; do
   cd $LOC
   cd ${dir}
   count
done
```

Or shorter (when your function count accepts a directory as parameter 1):

```
find $LOC -type d | xargs count
```

I now see you do not want to use *find* or *ls -R* (recursive function). Then you should make your own recursive function, something like

```
function parseDir {
   ls -d */ $1 | while read dir; do
      count
      parseDir $1/$dir
   done
}
```

Comment: According to a comment `find` is not allowed. However, the OP should have written this in the actual question. This solution is what any future internaut will want, bar the `find` exception.

Answer (score 1):

If you really must avoid recursion, try this. It completely recursion-free:

```
#!/bin/bash

count() {
   echo counting "$1"
}

todo=(Testing)

while test ${#todo[@]} != 0
do
   doit=("${todo[@]}")
   todo=()
   for dir in "${doit[@]}"
   do
      for entry in "$dir"/*   # If the directory is empty, this shows an entry named "*"
      do
         test -e "$entry" || continue   # Skip the entry "*" of an empty directory
         count "$entry"
         test -d "$entry" || continue
         todo+=("$entry")
      done
   done
done
```

Comment: it's uni work, I didn't expect people to rewrite the entire thing, and now that I see the full solution, it's really hard not to just use it, but that'd be plagiarism, *sigh* the moral dilemma

Comment: Rewriting is much less work then showing you line by line what's wrong.

Comment: @MeeranBala-Kumaran: Keep in mind that arrays are only available since Bash 3, I think. It's possible they aren't available on the machine your teacher will use. Just saying.

Comment: @HansKlünder I know, and I appreciate you doing this for me, thank you. I just really don't wanna copy someone elses' work and risk getting 0 in my coursework.. I've saved your solution as a last option, if I really can't fix mine, or come up with one that hasn't been given to me.

Comment: If your teacher does not have, eplace the array by a simpler and more error-prone string that contains directories separated by blanks. You use test -z "$todo" and a few similar changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this will work, but it’s an interesting question I couldn't stop thinking about.

```
while true ; do
    for word in "$(echo *)" ; do
        if [[ -d "$word" ]] ; then
            d[$((i++))]="$PWD"/"$word"
        elif [[ -f "$word" ]] ;then
            f[$((j++))]="$PWD"/"$word"
        fi
    done

    [[ $k -gt $i ]] && cd ..
    cd "$d[$((k++))]" || break
done
```