# Array objects with whitespace in names not conjoined

Tags: arrays, bash

```
AVAILABLEDIR=("${AVAILABLEDIR[@]}" "$(ls $LOC -AFl | sed "1 d" |  grep "/$" | awk '{ print $9,$10 }')")
```

I'm trying to create an array using this command, however when it adds objects to the array, it adds `$9` and `$10` seperately, is there a way to tell the array to have both of these arguments joined? This is what I want:

```
[Directory 1/] [Directory 2/] [Directory 3/]
```

instead of

```
[Directory] [1/] [Directory] [2/] [Directory] [3/]
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: It looks like you ask about that homework twice a day, and at least one of my answers [shows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730620/infinite-while-loop-in-bash-script/27730910#27730910) how to scan a directory even if the entry names contains spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use a pipeline headed by `ls` for this; just use a glob.

```
pushd "$LOC"
AVAILABLEDIR+=( */ )
popd
```

`pushd` works like `cd`, but saves the current directory on a stack before changing. `*/` is a pattern that matches all directory names in the current directory; `+=` appends the matching directories to the current value of `AVAILABLEDIR`. `popd` removes the directory name from the top of the stack and `cd`s there. The `pushd/popd` combination is the easiest way to add `Directory 1`, rather than `$LOC/Directory 1`, to the array.

Comment: I don't really understand this code, is there a simpler way?

Comment: I literally do not know how this could be any simpler (using length as the measurement of complexity) but I will add an explanation for what each part does, which is worth understanding.